# How to dynamically apply changes to app.config on program start?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, desktop-application

My program uses some environment data, which is referenced in 'app.config' file:

```
<configuration>
...
   <EnvUnderTest path="settings_a.xml" />
...
<configuration>
```

It's needed to switch between this data from times to times. But, I don't like an idea to change 'app.config' file directly. So, I thought that it'll be much better if 'path' parameter would be changed right after program start.

Could you tell me, how it could be done?

I've tried the following code:

```
string te = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnvUnderTest "]; 
Configuration cfg = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

but *te* variable value is *null*, so I have no idea how could I access this parameter value on runtime.

Comment: If you need to change those values, and you know the desired value, what makes sense to save it in `app.config` in the first place?

Comment: Actually you're right.
But the problem is that settings are loaded into 'cfg' variable. And ConfigurationManager::OpenExeConfiguration() doesn't specify what file is loaded.
And If I knew how to load preferences from another file, I'd prefer to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the Config file appropriately. Try this:

```
<configuration>
...
    <appSettings>

        <add key="EnvUnderTest" value="settings_a.xml" />
    </appSettings>
...
</configuration>
```

This should work with the code you've provided. Obviously, any other key you wish to add should also be under `<appSettings>`.

Comment: Yes, it works. But there is still a problem: how to place this configuration is 'cfg' variable. By default, it operates with old-style 'EnvUnderTest' tag

Comment: I did not understand your question. Can you please rephrase ?